# Tess4j in glassfish ERROR:java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RESOURCE_PREFIX

Tags: glassfish-3, tesseract, tess4j

I'm using Tess4j 2.0.0 in oracle-glassfish3.1.1, Exception is:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RESOURCE_PREFIX
>     at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.(LoadLibs.java:60)
>     at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.(TessAPI.java:40)
>     at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:360)
>     at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:273)
>     at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:256)
>     at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:237)
>     at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:221)
>     at cn.uxcard.util.CaptchaUtil.getCaptcha(CaptchaUtil.java:29)
>     at cn.uxcard.util.HttpConnection.getCaptcha(HttpConnection.java:60)
>     at cn.uxcard.util.HttpConnection.tryCaptcha(HttpConnection.java:78)
>     at cn.uxcard.util.HttpConnection.login(HttpConnection.java:90)
>     at cn.uxcard.util.HttpConnection.tryLogin(HttpConnection.java:121)
>     at cn.uxcard.util.HttpConnection.init(HttpConnection.java:148)
>     at cn.uxcard.util.HttpUtil.getConnection(HttpUtil.java:28)
>     at cn.uxcard.executor.FetchTodayConsumeRecordExecutor.run(FetchTodayConsumeRecordExecutor.java:29)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

the glassfish load com.sun.jna.Platform class, don't use WEB-INF/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar but use "bundle://185.0:1/com/sun/jna/Platform.class".
Can I change the glassfish classload order and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue while trying to develop a web application with Tess4j and after some research found out that class loaders in the GlassFish Server runtime follow a delegation hierarchy as specified in this link >>

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/6nmndgmhp/index.html

Accordingly, placing the jar files (tess4j.jar, jna.jar, jai_imageio.jar, commons-io-2.4.jar) in the system extensions directory (*domain-dir/lib/ext*) resolved this error for me.

**Versions Used:**

• GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2
• jdk-7u80-windows-i586.exe
• NetBeans IDE 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, I switch the JRE version to my eclipse Execution environment Java-SE-1.7(jre7) and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency on JNA `RESOURCE_PREFIX` string constant has been removed in the latest releases 3.4.9 (for Tesseract 3.05.01) and 4.0.2 (for Tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1). The library can now be used with Glassfish.